# The input number value on click and on change using control buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What event should I use to get an input number value where the value is changed typing or changed with button,

```
<p><input id="multiplier" type="number"></p>
```

`change` doesn't work when types only using the buttons

```
$('#multiplier').change(function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
 let multiplier = document.getElementById("multiplier");
 
  multiplier.addEventListener("input",function(){
    let value = this.value;
    console.log(value)
  })
```

```html
<p><input id="multiplier" type="number"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two event triggers like this:

```js
$('#multiplier').on('keyup change', function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
   console.log(value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input id="multiplier" type="number"></p>
```

Comment: It doesn't work when type,my question is i f its posible tomake it ork on keyup and on change in only one event

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't understand. I changed my answer, but input is probaly better!